# Export a Pyramid to VRML format

Tags: export

How do you export a `Pyramid` to `vrml` format in *Mathematica* ?
I have been trying to do this the following way

```
graph = Graphics3D[Pyramid[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]];
Export["test.wrl", graph]
```

But I get an error:

> Export::nodta: Graphics3D contains no data that can be exported to the VRML format.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I would say an issue for support@wolfram.com. Pyramids should not be impossible to export to vrml.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely straightforward, but as it turns out you can use `MeshCells` together with `DiscretizeGraphics`:

```
MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeGraphics[Pyramid[]], 2]

(*{Polygon[{{-1., -1., 0.}, {1., -1., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}}], 
 Polygon[{{-1., -1., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}, {-1., 1., 0.}}], 
 Polygon[{{1., -1., 0.}, {1., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}}], 
 Polygon[{{1., 1., 0.}, {-1., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}}], 
 Polygon[{{-1., -1., 0.}, {-1., 1., 0.}, {1., 1., 0.}, {1., -1., 0.}}]}*)
```

This should export just fine.